# Project class references in SonarQube or any other tool

Tags: plugins, reference, tree, sonarqube, relation

Is it possible to generate a reference tree of project classes in SonarQube or in any other tool?  I would like to see for a specific class which other classes it references. Ideally, maybe we could put this information for all classes in one view.

Answer (score 0):

No this use case, can't be covered with SonarQube.